# Удалить поле из объекта при условии

Tags: javascript, объекты

Нужно удалить из объекта поле при условии, когда другое поле равно чему-то:

```js
let guys = {
    name: 'Lilia',
    gender: 'female',
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name: 'Robert',
    gender: 'male',
    age: 51
  }, {
    name: 'Katarina',
    gender: 'female',
    age: 19
  }, {
    name: 'Carolyn',
    gender: 'female',
    age: 35
  }, {
    name: 'Michael',
    gender: 'male',
    age: 31
  };
```

и вот когда `gender = 'female` нужно удалить у них `age`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let guys = [
  { age: 23, gender: 'female', name: 'Lilia' },
  { age: 51, gender:   'male', name: 'Robert' },
  { age: 19, gender: 'female', name: 'Katarina' },
  { age: 35, gender: 'female', name: 'Carolyn' },
  { age: 31, gender:   'male', name: 'Michael' }
];

guys.forEach(user => {
  if( user.gender === "female" ) delete user.age;
});

console.log( guys );
```

Или, если угодно, классический цикл:

```
for( let i = 0; i < guys.length; i++ ) {
  let user = guys[i];
  if( user.gender = "female" ) {
    delete user.age;
  }
}
```

Comment: OPTIMUS PRIME, не меняй код в исходнике...